# why axios post method return Promise{<pending>}?

Tags: reactjs

I want to use axios post method in reactjs in a submit function, but keep got axios return Promise{}

I tried to put console.log in each step but no one come out. I tried to change fetch also, but got same issue.

```
     let product_Id = this.state.value        
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/debug',{product_Id})
           .then(function(response){
             console.log("response",response)
           })
           .catch(function (error) {
             console.log("catch",error);
           })
           .finally(function(error){
             console.log("finally",error);
           })
```

I except the post can return the value from the endpoint.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! The code snippet you provided seems correct. Would you be able to add the rest of the code?

Comment: do you see your request in the `network panel` of browser devTools?